# How to define the OpenAPI `securitySchemes` for openapi-generator to pick up the `token` attribute?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I would like to use https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator to generate a python sdk from the yaml behind https://api-docs.firefly-iii.org/

Currently, the YAML contains this `securityScheme`:

```yaml
securitySchemes:
    firefly_iii_auth:
      type: oauth2
      description: Default OAuth2 flow
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: https://demo.firefly-iii.org/oauth/authorize
          tokenUrl: https://demo.firefly-iii.org/oauth/token
          refreshUrl: https://demo.firefly-iii.org/oauth/token
          scopes: {}
    local_bearer_auth:
      description: Optional Bearer token flow
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

The above schema is translated by openapi-generator to the following snippet in `configuration.py`:

```py
class Configuration(object):
    _default = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        host=None,
        discard_unknown_keys=False,
        disabled_client_side_validations="",
        server_index=None,
        server_variables=None,
        server_operation_index=None,
        server_operation_variables=None,
        access_token=None,
    ):
        ...
        self.access_token = None
```

I'm start an openapi client with

```py
configuration = openapi_client.Configuration(
  host = os.environ["FIREFLY_III_API_URL"],
  access_token = os.environ["FIREFLY_III_TOKEN"]
)
client = openapi_client.ApiClient(configuration)
```

Changing `self.access_token = access_token` makes authentication to work. Without it, the server returns an Unauthenticated error.

How could I extend the YAML schema to get the right generated code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setter to set access_token something as below:
`configuration.access_token = 'AccessToken'`
instead of the constructor:

```
object.Configuration(
    host = "HostURL",
    access_token = 'AccessToken')
```

I think due to a bug 'Access_token' in constructor is set to none, but using setter its working.